# What's the fastest way for a true sinatra(ruby/rack) after_filter?

Tags: ruby, performance, sinatra, callback

Okay it's a simple task.  After I render html to the client I want to execute a db call with information from the request.

I am using sinatra because it's a lightweight microframework, but really i up for anything in ruby, if it's faster/easier(Rack?).  I just want to get the url and redirect the client somewhere else based on the url.

So how does one go about with rack/sinatra a real after_filter.  And by after_filter I mean after response is sent to the client.  Or is that just not dooable without threads?

I forked sinatra and added after filters, but there is no way to flush the response, even send_data which is suppose to stream files(which is obviously for binary) waits for the after_filters.

I've seen this question: [Multipart-response-in-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367151/multipart-response-in-ruby-rack) but the answer is for rails. And i am not sure if it really flushes the response to the client and then allows for processing afterwards.

Rack::Callbacks has some before and after callbacks but even those look like they would run before the response is ever sent to the client here's [Rack::Callbacks](http://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/blob/ec0fb58ee4782b29483cba58833d1a67ac33252e/lib/rack/contrib/callbacks.rb)  implementation(added comment):

```
def call(env)
  @before.each {|c| c.call(env) }
  response = @app.call(env)
  @after.each {|c| c.call(env) }
  response 
  #i am guessing when this method returns then the response is sent to the client.
end
```

So i know I could call a background task through the shell with rake. But it would be nice not to have too...  Also there is [NeverBlock](http://www.espace.com.eg/neverblock) but is that good for executing a separate process without delaying the response or would it still make the app wait as whole(i think it would)?

I know this is a lot, but in short it's simple after_filter that really runs after the response is sent in ruby/sinatra/rack.

Thanks for reading or answering my question! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modified run_later port to rails to do the trick the file is available here:

http://github.com/pmamediagroup/sinatra_run_later/tree/master

Comment: That URL doesn't work.  I believe it was updated to http://github.com/pmamediagroup/sinatra_run_later/tree/master

Comment: This is no longer necessary!  :-) Yeah!!!  Jimmy Schementi added working after filters to Sinatra in version 1.0 (I haven't verified this yet though)  Check the changes @ http://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/CHANGES

Comment: not true; Sinatra's `after` filters run after the route, but before the response is sent to the user (allowing you a last chance to modify the response).

Comment: Thanks @Phrogz for pointing this out!  What about sinatra_run_later then?