# Is there a quick and easy way to log custom data after a response has been sent in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I see there are "after" filters.  However, in my tests they are not executed after the response has been sent, but rather before the response has been sent.  Maybe I missed something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way for a true sinatra(ruby/rack) after_filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513491/whats-the-fastest-way-for-a-true-sinatraruby-rack-after-filter)

Answer (score 1):

Sinatra [README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro):

> After filters are evaluated after each request within the same context and can also modify the request and response. Instance variables set in before filters and routes are 
>   accessible by after filters:

If the after filters can modify the response, then obviously they run before the response is sent.