# Sinatra - terminate server from request

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

I want to be able to terminate a Sinatra app from a request, e.g. with the following route:

```
post '/terminate' do
  Thread.current.kill
end
```

Implementing it like this is a bit abrupt.  I'd rather the request completed, returned an HTTP OK message, and then Sinatra shut down gracefully.

Is there a hook to do this?

**Edit:**

My application is a lightweight mock server used for receiving webhook notifications.  I will be using multiple servers like this on the same machine (different ports), so need to avoid any global methods of starting/stopping.

My requirement is driven by the fact that each server must run in its own Ruby instance, hence no communication between my tests and the server other than via the REST interface.

I'm using the default `thin` server to run Sinatra.  So far my code is just a subclass of Sinatra::Base, started using `run!` from within the code.  This is nice and simple, I can make standalone scripts to instantiate each server, I just need to have a way of stopping them.

Comment: depending on the rack server that you are running sinatra in, you could send it some termination signal like `SIGKILL`. this should perform a graceful shutdown of the server. have a look at the documentation of your webserver.

Comment: @phoet see my expanded question for more details.  If you think there's a way to select specific `thin` servers and send them `SIGKILL`s, please submit as an answer.

Comment: if you want to implement a lightweight test double, i think it might be best to do this via simple server-socket. that way you could have total control over the runtime behavior and the number of calls it should receive. it's not really hard to do either.

Comment: The test double is already written, and working well...it was easy using Sinatra.  This is the only outstanding issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to come down to a problem with running code *after* the response is sent. Not a very easy task:

[What's the fastest way for a true sinatra(ruby/rack) after_filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513491/whats-the-fastest-way-for-a-true-sinatraruby-rack-after-filter)

That said, it looks like you could do something like this (though I haven't tested it):

```
post '/terminate' do
  body "I'll be back..."
  # maybe clean things up here...
  logger.info "Received terminate request!"
  Thread.new { sleep 1; Process.kill 'INT', Process.pid }
  halt 200
end
```

Seems very "hacky", but I question the point of being able to remotely shutdown a web server via a call to a URI anyway.  ;-)

Comment: In this context I don't mind hacky...it's a lightweight test server. Will try this when I'm in the office tomorrow.  +1 for 'I'll be back!'!