# Kill all threads on terminate

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to create an app in ruby which can be started from command line and it does two things: runs a continous job (`loop` with `sleep` which runs some action [remote feed parsing]) with one thread and sinatra in a second thread. My code (simplified) looks like that:

```
require 'sinatra'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    "Hello!"
  end
end

threads = []

threads << Thread.new do
  loop do
    # do something heavy
    sleep 10
  end
end

threads << Thread.new do
  MyApp.run!
end

threads.each { |t| t.join }
```

The above code actually does it's job very well - the sinatra app is started an available under 4567 port and the `do something heavy` task is beeing fired each 10 seconds. However, i'm not able to kill that script.

I'm running it with `ruby app.rb` but killing it with ctrl + c is not working. It kills just the sinatra thread but the second one is still running and, to stop the script, i need to close the terminal window.

I was trying to kill all the threads on SIGNINT but it's also not working as expected

```
trap "SIGINT" do
  puts "Exiting"
  threads.each { |t| Thread.kill t }
  exit 130
end
```

Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you see the output for your `puts "Exiting"` ?

Comment: unfortunately, i don't

Comment: That obviously means that your `trap` isn't working. As a side-note, I recommend exiting threads via `thread.exit` rather than `Thread.kill(thread)` - it's more succinct.

Comment: Try adding this line: `Thread.abort_on_exception = true`

Comment: Also, if that doesn't work, I would try: `trap('INT') { exit! }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trap ctrl-c, change "SIGINT" to "INT".

```
trap("INT") {
  puts "trapping"
  threads.each{|t|
    puts "killing"
    Thread.kill t
  }
}
```

To configure Sinatra to skip catching traps:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :traps, false
  end
  ...
```

Reference: Ruby [Signal module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Signal.html)

To list the available Ruby signals: `Signal.list.keys`

Reference: [Sinatra Intro](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html)

(When I run your code and trap INT, I do get a Sinatra socket warning "Already in use". I presume that's fine for your purposes, or you can solve that by doing a Sinatra graceful shutdown. See [Sinatra - terminate server from request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523889/sinatra-terminate-server-from-request))

Comment: After changing SIGNINT to INT, all i'm getting after pressing ctrl+c is `^C== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)` and i'm still not able to terminate that bastard

Comment: @mbajur it seems sinatra is trapping the signals before it gets to your signal, here https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/4e92d604be5269b1d6527a6093f112d10b5b9d7f/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1523-L1528, so you might want to `set :trap, false` in the `configure` block

Comment: I added Sinatra code for you - it's the same code that @bjhaid is suggesting, except plural 'traps'.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but Trap has one big disadvantage - it gets overriden by the webserver. For example, Puma sets several traps which basically makes your one never to be called.

The best workaround is to use `at_exit` which can be defined multiple times and Ruby makes sure all blocks are called. I haven't tested this if it would work for your case tho.