# download multiples files in one request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't know if it is posible, but I'd like to download a group of pdf's in only one request

this is the way I download a particular invoice:

```
def show
   @invoice = Invoice.find_by_invoice_hash params[:hash]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml do
      send_data File.read( @invoice.xml_path ), type: 'text/xml', filename: "invoice_#{ @invoice.id }.xml", disposition: 'attachment'
    end

    format.pdf do
      render :pdf   => @invoice.hash,
      layout: 'pdf',
      footer: {
        right: "printed at: #{Date.today}"
      }
    end
  end
end
```

What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: You could archive the files (zip/tar/etc..) together into a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP does not care about what you send in one response. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/410955/448141) for sending complex response data in rails.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is designed to return only one file at a time. You can tar or zip the files together and return that result.